# __getattribute__ running into recursion

Tags: python, getattribute

I have a filesystem object (let it be `fs`). The object makes use of jwt token for authentication. When we create the filesystem object, the authentication is done. Once, we have the object, we can call method like `ls` to list the directory, etc. The token has some expiration time.

The issue is when I call `fs.ls('/')`, there is no validation in the backend for the token like is token still valid or not. What I want is, when ever there is call to a method on the object, I will intercept the call and check for the token expiration. If it is about to expire will update the token.

Searching and reading on SO, I came to about `__getattribute__`. But my code is not working as expected. Sometimes I am getting recursion error or sometimes I am getting null values.

This code gives recursion error:

```
class FileSystem(adlfs.FileSystem):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:            
        self.name, self.token = self._get_token()

        if self.name is not None:
            kwargs["name"] = self.name
        if self.token is not None:
            kwargs["token"] = self.token

        self.exp = self.token.token.expires_on

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)

def _get_token(self) -> (str, 'Credential'):
    return name, token

def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    attribute = super().__getattribute__(attr)
    if callable(attribute):
        curr_time = int(time.time())
        if curr_time > self.token_exp:
            def refresh_token(*args, **kwargs):
                self.name, self.token = self._get_token()
                self.token_exp = updateTokenExpiration(self.token)
                super().updateConnection()
                return attribute(*args, **kwargs)
            return refresh_token
        else:
            return attribute
    else:
        return attribute
```

Comment: A reproducible example would help. Maybe you can fall back to using `__getattr__` or `__dict__` ?

Comment: If you access `self` attributes in the function, that will call `self.__getattribute__()` again.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach `__getattr__` won't be useful because all method exists.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in `__getattribute__()` all occurrences of `self.something` need to be replaced with `super().__getattribute__('something')` (unless they are targets of an assignment or `del`).

In your case that can be relaxed for non-callables (as for them your implementation of `__getattribute__()` just calls `super().__getattribute__(...)`, practically without doing anything more), but for callables it still needs to be adjusted, for example:

```
# before adjustment:
self.name, self.token = self._get_token()

# after adjustment:
self.name, self.token = super().__getattribute__('_get_token')()
```

Otherwise your implementation calls itself, so that an *infinite recursion* occurs.

Replacing simple attribute access with such calls can, however, be tedious if you have many such places in your `__getattribute__()`...

A possible trick is to use in your definition of `__getattribute__()` only such attributes/methods of `self` that are specially named, e.g. with `_ga_` at the beginning of their names, and *filter out* such names from the customized behavior of your `__getattribute__()`, e.g.:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if name.startswith('_ga_'):
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
    ...here the actual part of your custom implementation
    ...in which you can freely use `self._ga_whatever...`
```

Comment: Getting error: TypeError : super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: Such an error from an argumentless `super()` call would mean that `self` is not an instance of the class the method is defined in. That would be very strange... But it's hard to guess what is actually wrong without the code of the whole class and the error's traceback.

Comment: got it working. Thanks!